# How to send upload image to server AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, file-upload

Have a request to server

```
{
    "body":{
        "user_id":"2",
        "message":"sdfdsfsd",
        "images":["http://hylaa-oss.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/icon/hylaa_583d2b9b8e280.jpeg","http://hylaa-oss.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/icon/hylaa_583d2b9b8e280.jpeg"],
        "feedback_id":1

    }
}
```

MY HTML

```
<div class="gt-clear">
            <div ng-repeat="step in stepsModel">
                <img width="100" height="100" class="thumb" ng-src="{{step}}" />
            </div>
            <input type='file' ng-model-instant onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(this)" />
             <div class="gt-left"><a href="#" class="add-btn-big"></a></div>
             <div class="gt-right btndown-reply"><a class="gt-btn-small"
                        ng-click="addReply(content.user_id, content.feedback_id, textareareply)">Reply</a>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Need to send image to server.
my JS:

```
$scope.stepsModel = [];

    $scope.imageUpload = function(element){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    }

    $scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.stepsModel.push(e.target.result);
        });
    }
    console.log($scope.stepsModel);





    $scope.addReply = function(id,feedid,text ) {
    var url = feedbackApiSet.reply;
      var data = {"body":{course_id: id, message: text, images:$scope.stepsModel , feedback_id: feedid }};
      console.log(data);
      httpService.postService(url, data).then(function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                $state.reload();

            })         


  }
```

1x1 pixel images is uploding fine. Because it have short name
Find mistake. It convert to base64. And file name to long. How to disable converting to base64 ?

Comment: Please create a Plunker of JSFiddle with your code.

Comment: One thing that sticks out is the `onchange` handler. You can simply attach an event handler by saying `onchage=imageUpload()` You already have access to the controller's scope in the view.

Comment: @frishi don't understand please show in code

Comment: @TomePejoski very hard to implement it on plunker. Get in console resultimages
:
Array[2]
0
:
"data:image

Comment: 1x1 pixel images is uploding fine. Because it have short name Find mistake. It convert to base64. And file name to long. How to disable converting to base64 ?